# Understanding CaseFeed

Tags: casefeed

I'm trying to figure out how CaseFeed Objects work. In a Feed Object, there seems to be no reference to the Object it should reference to, like an email. How could i recreate a Casefeed by myself? Are some Master-Detail Relationships involved and if so, how can i look them up by myself? In Salesforce, so many things feel like magic and it's hard to understand the logic and structures behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on `CaseFeed` is a bit hard to find in the Salesforce Objects Reference Guide as it is under [*Standard*ObjectNameFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_associated_objects_feed.htm?search_text=casefeed)

- `ParentId` - points at the Case
- `RelatedRecordId` - ContentVersionId of a `ContentPost`; null otherwise
- `Type` - will be `EmailMessageEvent` for email events in the Case Feed (sent/received)

`CaseFeed` objects can't be directly created; they are implicitly created when a `FeedItem` whose `ParentId` is a `Case SObjectType` is inserted via DML (or in the situation of email events, when the Case sends an email or receives an email).

Note that Case emails can be found in the `EmailMessage` object.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
But how do i now which email correspond to the FeedItem? Is this a Master-Details relationship? Do i have to make a query for every type of a FeedItem?